# How to lookup a value and return multiple unique values to a single cell - comma separated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I am attempting to lookup a unique identifier (Product Number) which is held in several different stock locations. For example:

```
   __A__     __B__       __C__         
1   Item #   Warehouse   Description
2  ABCD-0001  WHSE 1      Red Label
3  ABCD-0001  WHSE 3      Red Label
4  QRST-0005  WHSE 2      2" Pipe
5  QRST-0005  WHSE 1      2" Pipe
6  LMNO-0002  WHSE 4      6" Pipe
7  LMNO-0002  WHSE 2      6" Pipe
```

And I want my lookup formula to list my results as such:

```
    __A__       __B__              __C__ 
1    ITEM      WAREHOUSE          Description
2  ABCD-0001   WHSE 1, WHSE 3      RED LABEL
3  QRST-0005   WHSE 2, WHSE 1      2" Pipe
4  LMNO-0002   WHSE 4, WHSE 2      6" Pipe
```

All of the functions that I have seen (INDEX-MATCH, VLOOKUP) can only list the results vertically in different cells. I would like to list the warehouses in the same cell and seperated by a comma.

I have attempted to create a User Defined Function in VBA that I saw on another post on this website. However, I continued to get a #VALUE error. My belief is that it is due to the lettering in my example where the one that I saw only contained numbers.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

The Function that I used initially was found from User BryanC. It looked like this:

```
   Public Function mylookup(inputrange As Range, match As Range) As String
   Dim arr() As Variant
   Dim d As Object
   Dim result As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim v As Variant
   Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   arr() = inputrange.Value

   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
       If arr(i, 1) = match Then
           d(arr(i, 2)) = 1
       End If
  Next i
  For Each v In d.Keys()
          result = result & v & ","
  Next v
      result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

  mylookup = result

  End Function
```

It very well could be that I have the function written correctly in VBA and then am not doing the formula correct. For that the user suggested =mylookup(A1:A7,B2)

Comment: It will be easier to help with debugging your function if you post it here.

Comment: Is the data sorted (or can it be), so that the matching item numbers are contiguous?  What is the maximum number of duplicate item numbers?

Comment: Yes I currently have the Item Numbers sorted so that any duplicates are all in chronological cells. The max number of duplicates is 10. Meaning one Item Number could possibly be and any or all of WHSE1-WHSE10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, though not elegant, way to do it.  Use the next column to build the warehouse lists:

[image]

The formula in cell D2 is:

```
=IF(A2=A1,D1&", "&B2,B2)
```

Copy that down the column as needed.  It looks at whether the Item # is the same as the previous record.  If it is, it concatenates the warehouse to the list.  Otherwise, it starts a new list.

Use the next column to create a filter that identifies the last record for each item number:

[image]

The formula in cell E2 is:

```
=IF(A2=A3,"",1)
```

Copy that down the column.  This looks at whether the current Item # matches the next one.  If so, it leaves the cell blank.  If it doesn't match, it means it is the last record for the Item # and has the complete warehouse list in the D column, so the filter gets a `1`.

Now you filter on E to show only records containing the complete list.  From there, you have the basis to create the output you want by copying, referencing cells, or viewing in place.  To view in place, move column D to the left and hide column B.  Here is the result after also hiding column E:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have now successfully done it both with an IF function as well as with the VBA function above. While your version is more simple, now that I have the code it is much faster to do the mylookup formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your *mylookup* is fine, you have to use it as `=mylookup(A1:B7,B2)`.

the `inputrange` must cover *columns A and B*. You are trying only with column A.

Comment: I am attempting _mylookup_ in cell column C and the formula looks like:                       =mylookup($A$1:$B$1591,B2) and I am still getting a #VALUE error.

Comment: Is the VBA code in a module? User Defined Functions can't be attached to a worksheet. You have to insert a module on *ThisWorkbook* and paste the code in the module.

Comment: Thanks for you help with this!!! I played around with it enough and finally figure it out. Instead of B2 as the second part of the formula, it should be A2. So it looks like this now:  =mylookup($A$1:$B$1591,A2).  Simple change but it made it work.